# Get all links inside a div and save them to a list

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I download a html site with WebClient and downloadString() and then I try to get all link between the  and them into a list.

After a few tries and 2 hours of work, 1 time I got all links, sometimes I just get one and sometimes I get none.

Here's a Sample of my code - I just let the Catch Block away for better readability.

```
List<string> getLinks = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < wikiUrls.Length; i++)
{
    try
    {
        string download = client.DownloadString(wikiUrls[i]);
        string searchForDiv = "<div class=\"wiki\">";
        int firstCharacter = download.IndexOf(searchForDiv);
        //if wiki doens't exists, go to next element of for loop
        if (firstCharacter == -1)
            continue;
        else
        {
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            document.LoadHtml(download);
            string nodes = String.Empty;
            var div = document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class=\"wiki\"]");
            if (div != null)
            {
                getLinks = div.Descendants("a").Select(node => node.GetAttributeValue("href", "Not found \n")).ToList(); 
                output.Text = string.Join(" ", getLinks);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. It's because

```
getLinks = div.Descendants("a").Select(node => node.GetAttributeValue("href", "Not found \n")).ToList();
```

GetLinks always got overwritten, because it's in a for loop. I solved it with this:

```
getLinks.AddRange(div.Descendants("a").Select(node => node.GetAttributeValue("href", String.Empty)).ToList());
```